# Creating then Canceling multiple alarms set with AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an app that allows the user to pick a pool of minutes.  So, they may pick 5, 15, 30 and 50 minutes.  Then, an alarmmanager alarm is set for each one of those at the same time with the following code (this block of code works great):

```
//SET ALL ALARMS
                for(int i = 0; i < spAlarms.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        if(!spAlarms[i].equals("")) {
                            int time = Integer.valueOf(spAlarms[i]);
                            final int intent_id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                            /*
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, time);
                            */
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Hop_Timer.this, Alarm_Receiver.class);
                            intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "Time for your " + spAlarms[i] + " min addition!");
                            intent_ids += "intent_id;";
                            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Hop_Timer.this, intent_id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
                            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) Hop_Timer.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (time*1000), sender);
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set alarm" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + (time*1000)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                //ALARMS SET
```

I want the user to be able to clear all the alarms and start over, even after setting them and hitting go.  I'm trying the AlarmManager.cancel class but it isn't working.  The documentation says if the intent is the same as the intent used to set the alarm then it will cancel it.  So, I use this block of code to cancel it:

```
String[] spCANCELS = intent_ids.split(";");

                //Cancel all previous set alarms
                for(int i = 0; i < spCANCELS.length; i++) {
                    try {
                        if(!spCANCELS[i].equals("")) {
                            int time = Integer.valueOf(spCANCELS[i]);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Hop_Timer.this, Alarm_Receiver.class);
                            intent.putExtra("alarm_message", "Time for your " + spCANCELS[i] + " min addition!");
                            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Hop_Timer.this, time, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
                            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) Hop_Timer.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                            am.cancel(sender);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }
                //All clear!
```

Alas, the alarms keep coming.  I test by putting in 10 different alarms at 5 seconds apart.  I let the first 3 or 4 alarms go off then hit my cancel button but the alarms keep coming (while all the field clear that are inside the click, so I know the click listener is working).

EDIT: Nevermind, I need to pay more attention when looking over my syntax.  This line: intent_ids += "intent_id;"; should not have had the variable intent_id in quotes.

Comment: Do you think this question/answer will be any use to anyone else? If not, I'd suggest deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I need to pay more attention when looking over my syntax. This line: intent_ids += "intent_id;"; should not have had the variable intent_id in quotes.

Comment: hope using different request code to set multiple alarms will work. Similar to using different values such as unique id